# Como Gerar números aleatórios sem repetição no Random?

Tags: java, eclipse, random

Até o momento consegui gerar os números aleatórios e armazenar, porém não faço ideia de como não gerar repetição.

Até o momento ficou assim:

```
package curso1;

import java.util.Random;

public class Curso7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//Verificação
boolean jaexiste;

//Vetor 
int[] numeros = new int[5];

//Gerar 5 numeros Aleatórios
Random radom  = new Random();
        int numeroTmp = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<5; i++) {
            numeroTmp=radom.nextInt(20);
            System.out.println(">"+numeroTmp);
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Adicione os valores em uma variável do tipo `List` e vá verificando a cada nova captura.

Comment: Poderia exemplificar? Sou iniciante

Comment: Votei para reabrir pois a solução que a resposta da pergunta linkada cita não é a solução desejada. Ele quer números aleatórios gerados pela classe `Random` e não por números armazenados numa lista.

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo um exemplo comentado. Fiz baseado no seu código, porém você poderia substituir `Integer[]` por `List<Integer>` e adaptar seu código. É bem fácil e caso queira posso colocar posteriormente.

**Exemplo Comum:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Curso7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Vetor
        Integer[] numeros = new Integer[50];

        //Gerar 5 numeros Aleatórios
        Random radom  = new Random();

        for(int i=0;i<50; i++) {
            int numeroTmp = radom.nextInt(20);

            /**
             * Transforma o array Integer para ArrayList e 
             * utilzia o método contains para verificar
             * se o valor já existe
             */
            boolean contains = Arrays.asList(numeros).contains(numeroTmp);

            /* Caso exista informa ao usuáiro */
            if (contains) {
                System.out.println(numeroTmp+" repetido");
            }
            /**
             * Caso não exista adiciona o valor na variável
             * indicada e exibe o valor para o usuário
             */
            else {
                numeros[i] = numeroTmp;
                System.out.println(">"+numeroTmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Demonstração: http://tpcg.io/0zM13d**</sup>

**Exemplo com Java 8:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Curso7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Vetor 
        int[] numeros = new int[50];

        //Gerar 5 numeros Aleatórios
        Random radom  = new Random();

        for(int i=0;i<50; i++) {
            int numeroTmp = radom.nextInt(20);

            /**
             * Utiliza a classe IntStream para verificar os 
             * valores através de uma expressão lambda
             *
             * Essa função irá funcionar semelhante ao forEach.
             */
            boolean contains = IntStream.of(numeros).anyMatch(x -> x == numeroTmp);

            /* Caso exista informa ao usuáiro */
            if (contains) {
                System.out.println(numeroTmp+" repetido");
            }
            /**
             * Caso não exista adiciona o valor na variável
             * indicada e exibe o valor para o usuário
             */
            else {
                numeros[i] = numeroTmp;
                System.out.println(">"+numeroTmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Demonstração: http://tpcg.io/YjFasr**</sup>

Comment: Vlw galera, consegui fazer usando boolean .

Answer (score 1):

Diretamente pela classe `Random` não é possível.

O que você pode fazer é utilizar a estrutura de dados [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), que possui como características a não repetição de valores e não manter qualquer ordem dos valores inseridos nela.

Dessa forma, você pode apenas adicionar os valores no `Set` sem se preocupar em ficar verificando se já existe ou não:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();
    Set<Integer> numeros = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        numeros.add(random.nextInt());
    }

}
```

Aqui foi utilizada a implementação [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), que tem por sua definição guardar os valores pelo seus respectivos *hash codes*. Obviamente, para que funcione conforme o esperado, o tipo que você vai armazenar precisa sobrescrever o método [`hashCode` da classe `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).
Nesse caso, como estamos *tipando* nosso `Set` com `Integer`, não precisamos nos preocupar, pois a classe `Integer` já sobrescreve esse método, então é "só usar".

---

Para saber mais, vale a [leitura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) sobre a estrutura de dados Set.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução mais simples seria você utilizar uma coleção chamada Set. Mas por que um set? Porque a principal característica dele é não aceitar números repetidos. Isso significa que, quando o método `nextInt()` gerar um número que já exista na sua lista, ele automaticamente não será adicionado. O próprio Set cuida da lógica de verificação de números repetidos.

Eis o código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Integer> numeros = new HashSet<>();

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            int n = random.nextInt(200);
            numeros.add(n);
        }

        //Como você criou um array de Integer, adicionei esta linha
        //abaixo para converter o Set em um array de Integer, mas
        //ela só é necessária caso você precise que a lista final
        //seja um array.

        Integer[] resultado = numeros.toArray(new Integer[numeros.size()]);

        //Imprimimos os valores usando um método bem bacana de uma 
        //classe chamada Arrays
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultado));

        //Rodando uma vez esse código, obtive:
        //[128, 64, 164, 36, 39, 41, 138, 171, 111, 19, 117, 183, 59]
```

}